# scientifically plausible aliens

Tags: science-based, aliens

When I was reading about that given out current knowledge about science, faster than light travel is scientifically impossible, I had to ask myself: What did the people "abducted by aliens" see then?!

Let's think about it then, but first the one rule: **assume that aliens really exist and do visit us**

- how is it scientifically possible?
- where do they most probably come from?
- and what does make them look so gray?

Or

Should I simply accept the fact that assumption "aliens do visit us" is wrong and the people claiming to be abducted are simply wrong?

Comment: Too wide - it is all opinions (WAG). No scientifically sound answer is possible IMHO.

Comment: It is way too wide and way too opinion based.  The 'Grey' image that you state here is most likely founded in a child's first image of their mother.  Our eyes are fully formed and developed from birth, but our brains are simply not capable of understanding what signals are coming from our eyes.  The most plausible 'first sight' of our mother is the grey alien face with big gigantic eyes staring at us because our minds simply cannot make out any more than that.  That is not to say 'abductions' claimants are all wrong, but it is a definite possibility for the origins of the big eyed Grey.

Comment: It is not excluded by science. For example an old civilization, which colonized the Galaxy by using [self-replicating spaceships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-replicating_spacecraft), might be using organic aliens as biological explorer robots assembled in our solar system. Personally, I find it very improbable, but it is plausible. But it would be very strange that they left so little fingerprints (radio signals, signs of construction in space, etc.)

Comment: This question is bad. You should rethink what you what to know. There is a question about the possibility of ftl travel, possibility of extraterrestrial life, possibility of people seeing alien just being crazy, and the assumption that aliens are grey ?

Comment: maybe you can ask at Skeptic exchange. They will also tell you that by definition we have no idea.

Comment: On related note from [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1235/).

Answer (score 7):

### How is it scientifically possible?

Interstellar travel **does not** require FTL travel. STL travel is entirely practical if aliens either use generation ships, do not age significantly, or some combination of two. We actually already have the technology for interstellar travel, we just do not want to go anywhere bad enough. A nearly immortal species with a more long term view and mature space technology might not have any reason not to travel.

### Where do they most probably come from?

Lacking FTL they'd need a nearby base, the hidden side of the moon would probably be most appealing "safe" place to observe humans. Or you can assume they have pacts with national governments that allow them to use bases on Earth.

As for the ultimate origin, I have no guess really. A civilization doing STL exploration could hop from star to star over millennia, even hundreds of millennia. The ultimate home system might well be beyond our current capability to detect Earth-like planets.

### And what does make them look so gray?

Lack of pigmentation? Genetically engineered species that spends millennia in spaceships travelling between stars does not really need pigmentation.

### Should I simply accept the fact that assumption "aliens do visit us" is wrong and the people claiming to be abducted are simply wrong?

Yes. It is the most reasonable assumption to make. Certainly the vast majority of UFO-theories make no sense or have much more likely origin than actual alien visitors.